# Запуск виртуальной машины через API

Tags: windows, api, виртуальная-машина

Если честно, не знаю даже как сформулировать правильно свой вопрос, я новичок. У меня арендована виртуальная машина на сайте https://zomro.com/ ; Из внешней панели управления можно включить машину, что мне и нужно сделать, только не вручную, а через API.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для это я так понял нужно сформировать запрос на авторизацию и последующее нажатие на кнопку "старт".
Как это сделать на Windows?

Comment: [VMManager KVM API, запустить виртуальную машину](https://docs.ispsystem.ru/vmmanager-kvm/razrabotchiku/vmmanager-kvm-api#VMmanagerKVMAPI-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Answer (score 1):

Открываете новое окно браузера в режиме инкогнито.
Открываете DevTools клавишей `F12` или `Ctrl+Shift+I`, переходите на вкладку `Network` (или  `Сеть`). Проверяете что первой кнопкой горит красный кружочек.

[image: вкладка network в devtools]

Далее идете на сайт. Авторизуетесь. Включаете свою машину. В консоли должны появляться разные запросы. Кликните правой кнопкой по любому запросу. Выберите в меню `Save All as HAR with content`.

[image: Контекстноме меню вкладки Сети]

Далее сохраняете har-файл.

С помощью утилиты [hargo](https://github.com/mrichman/hargo) и [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) можно запустить последовательность сохраненных в har - запросов.

Открываете командную строку или терминал. И набираете команду:

```
 hargo run имя_файла.har
```

Собственно, пожалуй все. Можно сохранить команду в bat-файл и запускать в любое время.

Comment: а какую команду для curl использовать? просто у меня ошибка

Comment: или как установить hargo?

Comment: Афигеть. Не знал. Надо попробовать "на кошках".

Comment: @AlinaHeldman, видимо через https://github.com/mrichman/hargo#running-hargo. Т.е. на комп надо поставить сам `go`.